# Getting two items from document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I'd like to extract data from HTML tags to form the following string:

`Adrien Petitpas, Julien M.Jaquet, Pascal Sciarini`

Where `Adrien`, `Julien M.` and `Pascal` are first names, and the other - last names.

This is how I extract name:

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.text.given-name')).map(s=>s.outerText)`

It gives me: `['Adrien', 'Julien M.', 'Pascal']`

Extracting surnames is also easy:

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.text.surname')).map(s=>s.outerText)`

How to combine my two selects, to get name and surname combined?

I tried with the script below, but I got wrong result: `'Adrien Petitpas'`, which is only the first person in tags.

Note that I'm interested in vanilla JavaScript.

Here's the page I have html text from: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261379420301244?via%3Dihub

```js
const names = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group'))
  .map(e => e.querySelector('span.text.given-name').outerText + ' ' + e.querySelector('span.text.surname').outerText)
  .join(', ');

console.log(names)
```

```html
<div id="author-group">
<span class="text given-name">Adrien</span><span class="text surname">Petitpas</span>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 106 128" width="19.875" height="24" class="icon icon-person">
       <path d="m11.07 1.2e2l0.84-9.29c1.97-18.79 23.34-22.93 41.09-22.93 17.74 0 39.11 4.13 41.08 22.84l0.84 9.38h10.04l-0.93-10.34c-2.15-20.43-20.14-31.66-51.03-31.66s-48.89 11.22-51.05 31.73l-0.91 10.27h10.03m41.93-102.29c-9.72 0-18.24 8.69-18.24 18.59 0 13.67 7.84 23.98 18.24 23.98s18.24-10.31 18.24-23.98c0-9.9-8.52-18.59-18.24-18.59zm0 52.29c-15.96 0-28-14.48-28-33.67 0-15.36 12.82-28.33 28-28.33s28 12.97 28 28.33c0 19.19-12.04 33.67-28 33.67"></path>
    </svg>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
       <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
    </svg>
</span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
          <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span><span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
  <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
             <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
          </svg>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau3" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
    <span class="text given-name">Pascal</span><span class="text surname">Sciarini</span>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to get the full name, query for the element that encapsulates that full name. Right now your HTML looks a bit curious, I'd expect `<span class="name"><span class="given-name">...</span><span class="surname">...</span></span>` or something similar. That is: the name is "everything that constitutes the name", with further markup to wrap the various parts of a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to complete some of the HTML to get it working, but here's one way to do it.

The problem in your current approach is that your `map` function receives an array with a single element. Hence the current output is the way it is.

I just changed your selector from `#author-group` to `#author-group .author`, to find all `.author`s under the `#author-group`

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group .author'))
  .map(e => e.querySelector('span.text.given-name').outerText + ' ' + e.querySelector('span.text.surname').outerText)
  .join(', '));
```

```html
<div id="author-group">
  <a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau1" href="#!">
    <span class="content">
<span class="text given-name">Adrien</span><span class="text surname">Petitpas</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
    <span class="content">
      <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span><span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau3" href="#!">
    <span class="content">
<span class="text given-name">Pascal</span><span class="text surname">Sciarini</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Another way, if you would like to just combine what you've figured out till now, would be to just concatenate the two arrays:

```
const givenNames = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.text.given-name')).map(s => s.outerText)

const surnames = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.text.surname')).map(s => s.outerText)

console.log(givenNames.map((givenName, i) => givenName + ' ' + surnames[i]).join(', '));
```

Comment: I very like your first approach. Could you have a look at the link to the web page in my edited question. I think I messed up with HTML and that's because your code won't work on original HTML.

Comment: @menteith I don't know what you mean. If the HTML is different, you can apply the same concept to find the right selector. My point is that if you want 3 authors, then you'll need a way to get the 3 elements.

Comment: Sure, I get it. The thing is if I run your code, there is an error. As I'm not a JS developer, changing code is not that easy for me.

Comment: @menteith From the page you've shared, I think you need `#author-group .author` as the selector. Looks like there is a class of `author` on some other element as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling` to get the element containing the surname.

```js
console.log(Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('span.text.given-name'), 
  e => e.textContent + ' ' + e.nextElementSibling.textContent
));
```

```html
<span class="text given-name">Adrien</span><span class="text surname">Petitpas</span>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 106 128" width="19.875" height="24" class="icon icon-person">
   <path d="m11.07 1.2e2l0.84-9.29c1.97-18.79 23.34-22.93 41.09-22.93 17.74 0 39.11 4.13 41.08 22.84l0.84 9.38h10.04l-0.93-10.34c-2.15-20.43-20.14-31.66-51.03-31.66s-48.89 11.22-51.05 31.73l-0.91 10.27h10.03m41.93-102.29c-9.72 0-18.24 8.69-18.24 18.59 0 13.67 7.84 23.98 18.24 23.98s18.24-10.31 18.24-23.98c0-9.9-8.52-18.59-18.24-18.59zm0 52.29c-15.96 0-28-14.48-28-33.67 0-15.36 12.82-28.33 28-28.33s28 12.97 28 28.33c0 19.19-12.04 33.67-28 33.67"></path>
</svg>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
   <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
</svg>
</span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
   <span class="content">
      <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span><span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
      <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
         <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
      </svg>
   </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the author anchors that contain the name spans. Then use `querySelector` to find the given name and surname inside of the author.

```js
const authors = document.querySelectorAll('.author');

const names = Array.from(authors).map(author => {
  const givenName = author.querySelector('.given-name');
  const surName = author.querySelector('.surname');
  return `${givenName.textContent} ${surName.textContent}`;
});

console.log(names);
```

```html
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
    <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span>
    <span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau3" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
    <span class="text given-name">Pascal</span>
    <span class="text surname">Sciarini</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `nextSibling` is useful in this context :

```js
let output = [];

document.querySelectorAll(".given-name").forEach( el => output.push(el.outerText + " " + el.nextSibling.outerText));

console.log(output);
```

```html
<span class="text given-name">Adrien</span><span class="text surname">Petitpas</span>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 106 128" width="19.875" height="24" class="icon icon-person">
   <path d="m11.07 1.2e2l0.84-9.29c1.97-18.79 23.34-22.93 41.09-22.93 17.74 0 39.11 4.13 41.08 22.84l0.84 9.38h10.04l-0.93-10.34c-2.15-20.43-20.14-31.66-51.03-31.66s-48.89 11.22-51.05 31.73l-0.91 10.27h10.03m41.93-102.29c-9.72 0-18.24 8.69-18.24 18.59 0 13.67 7.84 23.98 18.24 23.98s18.24-10.31 18.24-23.98c0-9.9-8.52-18.59-18.24-18.59zm0 52.29c-15.96 0-28-14.48-28-33.67 0-15.36 12.82-28.33 28-28.33s28 12.97 28 28.33c0 19.19-12.04 33.67-28 33.67"></path>
</svg>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
   <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
</svg>
</span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
   <span class="content">
      <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span><span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
      <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
         <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
      </svg>
   </span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau3" href="#!">
<span class="content">
<span class="text given-name">Pascal</span><span class="text surname">Sciarini</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a good selector and a forEach

```js
const names = []
document.querySelectorAll('#author-group span.text')
  .forEach((span,i) => { 
    if (span.classList.contains("given-name")) names.push(span.textContent); 
    else names[names.length-1] += ` ${span.textContent}`
  })
console.log(names)
```

```html
<div id="author-group">
<span class="text given-name">Adrien</span><span class="text surname">Petitpas</span>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 106 128" width="19.875" height="24" class="icon icon-person">
       <path d="m11.07 1.2e2l0.84-9.29c1.97-18.79 23.34-22.93 41.09-22.93 17.74 0 39.11 4.13 41.08 22.84l0.84 9.38h10.04l-0.93-10.34c-2.15-20.43-20.14-31.66-51.03-31.66s-48.89 11.22-51.05 31.73l-0.91 10.27h10.03m41.93-102.29c-9.72 0-18.24 8.69-18.24 18.59 0 13.67 7.84 23.98 18.24 23.98s18.24-10.31 18.24-23.98c0-9.9-8.52-18.59-18.24-18.59zm0 52.29c-15.96 0-28-14.48-28-33.67 0-15.36 12.82-28.33 28-28.33s28 12.97 28 28.33c0 19.19-12.04 33.67-28 33.67"></path>
    </svg>
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
       <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
    </svg>
</span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
          <span class="text given-name">Julien M.</span><span class="text surname">Jaquet</span>
  <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 102 128" width="19.125" height="24" class="icon icon-envelope">
             <path d="m55.8 57.2c-1.78 1.31-5.14 1.31-6.9 0l-31.32-23.2h69.54l-31.32 23.19zm-55.8-24.78l42.94 32.62c2.64 1.95 6.02 2.93 9.4 2.93s6.78-0.98 9.42-2.93l40.24-30.7v-10.34h-102zm92 56.48l-18.06-22.74-8.04 5.95 17.38 21.89h-64.54l18.38-23.12-8.04-5.96-19.08 24.02v-37.58l-1e1 -8.46v61.1h102v-59.18l-1e1 8.46v35.62"></path>
          </svg>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau3" href="#!">
  <span class="content">
    <span class="text given-name">Pascal</span><span class="text surname">Sciarini</span></div>
```